# Erro ao usar string do values

Tags: java, android, string, value

Olá, estou usando string dentro de values.

Está tudo funcionando bem, mas quando a frase é composta por algo que vem do banco (por exemplo) e uma string, ele está colocando números ao invés do texto.

```
numeroAvaliacoes.setText(" " + object.getInt("avaliacoes") + R.string.avaliacoesesp);
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Sei que poderia colocar dois TextViews, mas tem coisa (por exemplo o a Intent de share que teria que colocar junto mesmo.

Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe `TextView` possui o método `setText` sobrecarregado de várias formas ([Segue a documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)):

Você pode passar o id ([resId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))) de uma String, e também a String ([CharSequence](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence))) em si, entre outras formas.

Se você concatenar o id com uma `String`, ela considera o valor do `id` (transforma o valor em String)

No seu caso, é necessário transformar seu id em String, para que se possa concatenar !

Para isso utiliza se o método [getString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)) do `Context`.

segue um exemplo:

```
numeroAvaliacoes.setText(" " + object.getInt("avaliacoes") +getContext().getString( R.string.avaliacoesesp ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Acontece que `R.string.avaliacoesesp` é um resource.

Faça assim:

```
numeroAvaliacoes.setText(" " + object.getInt("avaliacoes") + getResources().getString(R.string.avaliacoesesp));
```